# What is the key that will let you connect with a wifi router even if you do not know the wep/wpa key?

Tags: router, wireless-networking, wep

My university teacher showed as at the "internet security" lesson that there is a key in your wifi router webpage settings that it may used to connect with it even if the wep/wpa key is changed. It's been some years now and can not get it contact. So, my question is which is that key?

Thank you.

Comment: Downvoter instead of hiding, can you please tell me the reason ?

Comment: I've reversed the downvote. I agree that this is a valid question.

Comment: @Randolph West ok then, deal. It was something I learned in university but I can't remember it or even find it now. But it exists.

Comment: I think it depends on the brand of router. Perhaps you were downvoted because you didn't provide specific details on make and model. Update your answer with that and perhaps someone will be able to assist.

Comment: I find this hard to believe...  I dont think you are remembering correctly.

Comment: Could just be referring to the key to access the webconfig page (the default one which is normally printed on the underside of the router.)

Comment: I downvoted and I'm not hiding: there is no such key, at least no universal key as is implied by the asker, though who knows what vulnerability for a specific make/model their teacher was referring to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no universal key. You can recover the key from a running system or crack a WEP key (WPA could be cracked as well, but it takes longer), but having a universal 'skeleton key' kind of defeats the points of having a key at all.

If you wanted to do a key recovery from a running windows system nirsoft has [wirelesskeyview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_key.html). Else you can crack it with [aircrack-ng](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/) in many cases.

Answer (score 1):

You should reset the router to factory settings.

Look in the router's manual for details, or do a search of the web for the router's model number for instructions on how to perform the factory reset. Most routers have a "reset" button, often it's very small and you will need to depress it with the point of a pen or another pointy tool.

After resetting the router, the encryption security on the wireless signal should be removed, and the default username and password should then be in place for the administration console (or "webpage settings"). Details should be provided in the router's manual.

Best of luck.